# Apache proxy module issue

Tags: php, apache2, mod-proxy

I want to redirect a url to an application on same apache server.My development environment is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.I enables the mod_proxy.But my url isn't redirecting to the desired application.Following is the code i put inside the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file.I put this bottom of the file but before the "VirtualHost" tag.

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from localhost
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /application_directory/ http://localhost/application/directory
ProxyPassReverse /application_directory/ http://localhost/application/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope a trailing "/" might help

```
ProxyPass /application_directory/ http://localhost/application/directory/
ProxyPassReverse /application_directory/ http://localhost/application/directory/
```

Comment: I added the backslash.But still no luck.